# error in using laravel session with the file driver

Tags: php, laravel, session

we have a webapp implemented using laravel 4.2.19.

all works well, except in some very rare occasions we get the error:

```
462 production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream' in /var/www/webapp/src/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:70
 463 Stack trace:
 464 #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/weba...', 70, Array)
 465 #1 /var/www/webapp/src/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(70): file_put_contents('/var/www/weba...', 'a:3:{s:6:"_toke...', 2)
 466 #2 /var/www/webapp/src/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/FileSessionHandler.php(69): Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->put('/var/www/weba...', 'a:3:{s:6:"_toke...', true)
 467 #3 /var/www/webapp/src/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php(236): Illuminate\Session\FileSessionHandler->write('ac4a0ff71ea5f0e...', 'a:3:{s:6:"_toke...')
 468 #4 /var/www/webapp/src/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(126): Illuminate\Session\Store->save()
 469 #5 /var/www/webapp/src/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(79): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->closeSession(Object(Illuminate\Session\Store))
 470 #6 /var/www/webapp/src/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
 471 #7 /var/www/webapp/src/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
 472 #8 /var/www/webapp/src/backend/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
 473 #9 /var/www/webapp/src/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
 474 #10 /var/www/webapp/src/backend/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
 475 #11 {main} [] []
```

it appears as laravel is saving the session to file.

this happens only about 10 times a month, but still it give those users a problem.

my guess is that something happens on the system which leads to this error.
something like another process running which opens too much files.

any ideas or thoughts on how i can investigate this?

thanks.

Comment: can I take a wild guess you're using a cloud hosting platform?

Comment: `file_put_contents($file, $data, LOCK_EX)`, probably. what exactly is it writing out to?

Comment: yes, this is a virtual server at a hoster, but again this happens very rare.

it writes to storage/session/<session_id>

Comment: i have noticed that randomly this error appears also in other processes. eg.: we have a backup process running 2x a day, where about 150 dbs are dumped and backup. this also fails (randomly) with [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./demo/migrations.ibd, error: 37

Comment: the hosting company changed the limit defined by numflock. now everything works ok.